# Trying to download a 2D array as .csv, but I'm getting a file back for each row

Tags: javascript, csv, export-to-csv

Here is my code:

```
function getRelease(idFiltered) {
  return fetch(`https://api.discogs.com/releases/${idFiltered}`, {
    'User-Agent': 'Dispodger/0.1',
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    if (data.message === 'Release not found.') {
      return { error: `Release with ID ${idFiltered} does not exist` };
    } else {
      const id = data.id;
      const artists = data.artists ? data.artists.map(artist => artist.name) : [];
      const country = data.country || 'Unknown';
      const released = data.released_formatted || 'Unknown';
      const genres = data.genres || [];
      const styles = data.styles || [];
      const tracklist = data.tracklist ? data.tracklist.map(track => track.title) : [];

      console.log(idFiltered);
      console.log(artists, country, released, genres, styles, tracklist)

      const rows = [
        [idFiltered, artists, country, released, genres, styles, tracklist],

      ];

      const ROW_NAMES = ["Release ID", "artists", "country", "released", "genres", "styles", "tracklist"];

      console.log(rows);

      let csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,"
      + ROW_NAMES + "\n" + rows.map(e => e.join(",")).join("\n");

      console.log(csvContent);

      var encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
      var link = document.createElement("a");
      link.setAttribute("href", encodedUri);
      link.setAttribute("download", "my_data.csv");
      document.body.appendChild(link); // Required for FF

      link.click();

    }
  });
}
```

It's pretty close to what I want, but I'm getting back one file per line of output, instead of appending each line to a single file. From what I can see, there seems to be a number of different ways to join the data into a csv file, like using a `for` loop, or `forEach()` method, with `push()` method to push each item into a new array.

I suppose the logic of what I'm trying to do is...

- Get the various data items for each release specified in the input file
- Join each data item into an array for each release
- Combine these arrays into a 2D array, separated by line breaks
- Output them preceded with the row headers followed by a line break

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Edit: the output should be something like this:

```
   Release ID,artists,country,released,genres,styles,tracklist\n
   1,The Persuader,Sweden,Mar 1999,Electronic,Deep House,Östermalm,Vasastaden,Kungsholmen,Södermalm,Norrmalm,Gamla Stan\n
   2,Mr. James Barth & A.D.,Sweden,Jun 1998,Electronic,Broken Beat,Techno,Tech House,A Sea Apart,Dutchmaster,Inner City Lullaby,Yeah Kid!\n
   3,Josh Wink,US,13 Jul 1999,Electronic,Techno,Tech House,Untitled 8,Anjua (Sneaky 3),When The Funk Hits The Fan (Mood II Swing When The Dub Hits The Fan),What's The Time, Mr. Templar,Vol. 2,Political Prisoner,Pop Kulture,K-Mart Shopping (Hi-Fi Mix),Lovelee Dae (Eight Miles High Mix),Sweat,Silver,Untitled,Boom Box,Track 2\n
   4,Faze Action,US,02 Nov 1999,Electronic,House,Deep House,Moving Cities,To Love Is To Grow,Isis,Heartbeat,Samba,Got To Find A Way,Kariba,Space Disco,In The Trees,Turn The Point (U.S. Version),Mas,Horizons\n
   5,Datacide,Germany,15 Jan 1995,Electronic,Abstract,Ambient,Downtempo,Flashback Signal,Flowerhead,Deep Chair,So Much Light,Sixties Out Of Tune\n
```

Now, I say *something like* that, because that is still not going to solve the problem that each comma-separated value is going to be in its own cell, whereas I actually want the genres, styles and tracklist for each data item to be combined into single cells, like this:

[Release ID][artists][country][released][genre 1, genre 2,...][style1, style 2,...][track1, track 2,...]

(where [] is a cell)

But I'm really not ready to try and solve that problem until I've got the output into a single file. If I try to solve two problems at once I'm almost bound to get into a muddle.

The docs of the site I'm accessing are at https://www.discogs.com/developers.

[image: This is what I'm logging in the console]

Comment: Looking discogs doc, I wonder if you're mixed up about the shape of the data.  It looks like the releases/id endpoint returns attributes of a *single* release. Many of those attributes are arrays. Can you add to your question a textual example CSV that you hope for?  Skimming the code, it looks like the rows will be of variable length, (many containing a single attribute), the columns will be incoherent, etc.

Comment: @danh OK, will try to add a textual example CSV that I hope for. Should be added in a few minutes. Thanks.

Comment: Good edit!  The core problem is that your data is **three dimensional**. If spreadsheets were better, you could have arrays in cells. Your release spreadsheet, wants to have one row per artifact. You're confronted with a design decision about how handle array data *within that row*.  Perhaps, just to get unstuck, consider using the first element of the array attributes (e.g. the first artist listed) as a *singular* attribute.

Comment: well by looking at your code, function getRelease only retrieves one release at a time. So you have to call it multiple times, return the data push it into array and then generate csv, best way would be api-query to load multiple once

Comment: @danh - I see what you mean about it being three dimensional. I assumed it was 2D but I can see now it is 3D. I'm not sure how to go about the 'singular attribute' idea, but will try to look into that, thanks.

Comment: @john Smith - "you have to call it multiple times, return the data push it into array" - I thought that's what `rows.map` was going to do, but it's obviously not working.

Comment: rows.map will just make the array a string in csv-format, but obviously rows only has one row inside (the release you were loding by id) this is why its only one row

Answer (score 2):

The first problem -- the deep problem -- is that the shape of the release artifact is two dimensional, so compiling several releases produces three dimensions. CSV and spreadsheets contain only two dimensions.

What to do? If a simple CSV is the requirement, one idea is to flatten the data by turning the array attributes into strings with non-comma delimiters. Another idea is to lose some data by truncating the arrays.  (Semantically, there's usually a "main artist" in a musical work, and maybe we only care about them?  It looks like the api returns a "role" in the artist array. Maybe that's a clue about who's the important artist?)

There's also the idea of multiple CSVs with "foreign key" references to one another that might capture all of the dimensions, but that's probably wrong for some downstream requirement.

Okay, so here are both "flattening ideas"

```
// this produces a single row of a releases table (demonstrating two ways to flatten):
// [ id, title, firstArtist, genre;genre;genre ]
//
function getOneRelease(idFiltered) {
  return fetch(`https://api.discogs.com/releases/${idFiltered}`, {
    'User-Agent': 'Dispodger/0.1',
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    if (data.message === 'Release not found.') {
      return { error: `Release with ID ${idFiltered} does not exist` };
    } else {
      // flatten this data to be one dimensional by
      // truncating the array attributes to their first element
      const artist0 = data.artists.length ? data.artists[0] : ''
            
      // flatten using some delimeter, NOT A COMMA, to join the array attribute
      // into a singular string
      const allGenres = data.genres.join(';');  // note the semicolon won't upset a csv parse
      return [ data.id, data.title, artist0, allGenres ]
    }
  })
}

// this produces an array of arrays, each inner array is a release
function getReleases(arrayOfIds) {
  const promises = arrayOfIds.map(id => getOneRelease(id));
  return Promise.all(promises)
}

// get releases and add a header to produce csv data
getReleases([1,2,3]).then(results => {
  const data = [ ['id', 'title', 'mainArtist', 'genres'], ...results ];
  // csv is the inner arrays joined by commas and those joined by \n
  const csv = data.map(r => r.join(',')).join('\n');
})
```

Comment: Good guy, expensive answer!

Comment: @danh - Thanks, I'm trying to follow this through now. Unfortunately my neighbour is blasting his music so my concentration is not so good now. I'm getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ] after element listcsv.js:99:17note: [ opened at line 99, column 13". and nothing is happening when I try to upload a file, so I think I've done something wrong. Was I supposed to leave in everything after `var encodedUri` in my original version?

Comment: @danh - tried it again with everything after `var encodedUri` left in, but I'm still getting the same error, and no action after I upload the input file. I'm confused by that very last round bracket as I can't find its partner? Probably faulty understanding and/or clumsy copy-paste on my part, but I can't seem to work it out.

Comment: @double-happiness - I didn't try to compile my suggestion, and it did contain a syntax error which I've just corrected.  I still can't guarantee correctness without setting up a rig and credentials to test with that api.  I hope you can understand the intent and meaning of the code to get working.  Incidentally, the error related to me trying to include "keys" in an array literal in the function that gets the release info.   Fixed now.

Comment: @danh - OK, thanks a lot. And yes, I do see where you are going with this. Just working out it's actually a 3D array and needs 'flattened' is a big step forward.

Comment: @double-happiness - did it work? you can let others know with a checkmark.

Comment: @danh - I've not tried it yet. Will try to come back to it by the weekend. Thanks.

Comment: @danh - I just tried this, but unfortunately I'm getting "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: arrayOfIds.map is not a function".

Comment: @double-happiness that's saying the value of the thing being passed to the getReleases function isn't an array. My dummy code passes `[1,2,3]`, which is an array. Please investigate what you're passing.

Comment: @danh - OK, I'll try that later. Thanks.